# getting JSON Data with Swift 4 and Xcode 9

Tags: json, swift

I've been trying to work with the below code to get my JSON data. It returns "Error after loading". I am using this JSON data in another application and it works. I'm trying to implement the new simplified method using Swift 4. The code does work to the point of the print statement "downloaded".

```
class MortgageRatesVC: UIViewController {
    final let url = URL (string:"http://mortgous.com/JSON/currentRatesJSON.php")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJason()
    }

    func downloadJason () {
        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("Oops Call for Help")
                return
            }

            print("downloaded")
            do
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let rates = try decoder.decode([LenederRates].self, from: data)
                print(rates)
            } catch {
                print("Error after loading")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Class

```
class LenederRates: Codable {
    let key : String
    let financial_institution : String
    let variable_rate : String
    let six_months : String
    let one_year : String
    let two_year : String
    let three_year : String
    let four_year : String
    let five_year : String
    //  let date : Date

    init(key: String, financial_institution: String, variable_rate: String, six_months: String, one_year: String, two_year: String, three_year: String, four_year: String, five_year: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.financial_institution = financial_institution
        self.variable_rate = variable_rate
        self.six_months = six_months
        self.one_year = one_year
        self.two_year = two_year
        self.three_year = three_year
        self.four_year = four_year
        self.five_year = five_year
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full error that you are getting?

Comment: it's not giving me a swift error. It just stops at the error in my code print("Error after loading"). It's not able to read the JSON I think!

Comment: Add `print(error)` to your `catch` branch to inspect the actual error you’re getting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get error unable to read data at "key" and financial_institution value in the json data.

Comment: You need to set the decoder dateDecodingStrategy to `.formatted` and pass a fixed format dateFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the missing property date in your `Codable` class. You need to set the decoder `dateDecodingStrategy` to `.formatted` and pass a fixed format dateFormatter. Btw I suggest changing your class for a struct, change your property names using the Swift naming convention camelCase and provide the custom CodingKeys:

```
struct LenederRates: Codable {
    let key: String
    let financialInstitution : String
    let variableRate: String
    let sixMonths: String
    let oneYear: String
    let twoYear: String
    let threeYear: String
    let fourYear: String
    let fiveYear: String
    let date: Date
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key, financialInstitution = "financial_institution", variableRate = "variable_rate", sixMonths = "six_months", oneYear = "one_year", twoYear = "two_year", threeYear = "three_year", fourYear = "four_year", fiveYear = "five_year", date
    }
}
```

---

```
let mortgousURL = URL(string:"http://mortgous.com/JSON/currentRatesJSON.php")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: mortgousURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
        dateFormat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormat)
        let rates = try decoder.decode([LenederRates].self, from: data)
        print(rates)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you for the great response and taking the time to rework the code. I am sure you can see that I am a Rookie. It amazes me the many ways that coding problems can be solved. Thank you once again!

Comment: @KevinProctor you should declare your array as an instance property of your table view controller. If you declare it inside your method it will go out of scope as soon as your method finishes. So add the declaration `var rates: [LenederRates] = []` in your table view controller (out of that method) and inside the data task closure `rates = try decoder...` and reload the table view at the next line

Comment: @KevinProctor I suggest you roll back your question edit to the original question. I suggest opening a new question if you still have issues with it.

Comment: Note that downloadLenderRates it is already an array of type `[LenederRates]`, if you set the another array `[downloadLenderRates]` you will be creating a new object of type `[[LenederRates]]`