# SWIFT 4 nested JSON Struct - Codable

Tags: json, swift4, codable

I'm having issues creating a struct to parse JSON in Swift 4. I'm able to parse small JSONs and JSONDecoder seems to work fine. Just need help to create a struct to parse JSON like that:

```
{
    "main": {
        "solutions": [
                    {
                    "exersises": [
                                     {
                                     "book_title": "test",
                                     "release_date": "2015-01-12T11:00",
                                     "price": 100,
                                     "additional": [
                                                   {
                                                   "item1": "test",
                                                   "item2": "test",
                                                   "number": 1
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                    "item1": "test2",
                                                    "item2": "test2",
                                                    "number": 2
                                                   }
                                                   ],
                                     "availability": "Yes",
                                     "item_id": 43534
                                     }
                                     ]


                    }

                    ]
    }
}
```

What kind of struct do I need to get to value of book_title for example?

Comment: I am not really sure you should use `struct` against `class` but what you need are nested types, e.g. `Exercise`, `Solution` etc.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted, it's a valid question, I upvote 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its really easy. Your main probem is most likely root element. Let me get first layer or two for you.

```
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(MainJSON.self, from: data)

class MainJSON: Codable {
    var main:SolutionJSON?
}

class SolutionJSON: Codable {
    var exercises:[ExercisesJSON]?
}

class ExercisesJSON: Codable {
    var bookTitle: String?
    var releaseDate: String?
    var price: Double?
    ... etc

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookTitle = "book_title"
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
        case price = "price"
    }
}
```

ExerciseJSON also uses Codable interface which lets remap json properties into swift properties if they don't match. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for, I couldn't figure out the logic for root elements. I had to add one more level actually to be able to display elements. Do you know how to access the book_title ? I'm trying decoded.main.solutions.exersises[0].book_title. and getting an error

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out:  print(decoded.main!.solutions![0].exersises![0].bookTitle!)

Comment: @MikeT I would use structures instead of classes and declare all properties non optional and constants

Comment: Btw releaseDate should be declared as date and set the decoder `dateDecodingStrategy`  to `.formatted` and provide a fixed-format dateFormatter to parse that string `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705410/2303865

Comment: Valid points guys. As for optionals/nonoptionals it really depends on data. Optionals prevent crashes if data is not available. Var vs let - probably good point. Most likely if you need to alter the value of your autodecoded object you are doing something wrong :). Struct vs class again - depends on the use. If you pass the thing around a lot, it should be class, if you consume it once - then yeah, struct works better. As for decoding strategy - once again good tip if you can be 100% sure date is always returned in same format.

Comment: MainJSON and SolutionJSON should conform to Codable protocol. Donna know why the code in the answer builds

Comment: Good tip Nikita, I wrote this without compiling. Will update the answer.

Answer (score -2):

i prefer to give a general solution not only for this condition

it is very simple just download and run this [MACOS APP](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport) from GITHUB 
run it in your mac by XCODE and but your JSON in it,
it will make Models for any complex JSON

[image]

**notes**

1 if JSON keys have a capital character in the first it will be small 
, so after copying model you need to change it like the JSON

2 if two JSON objects have the same structure and the same key names it will be only one model

Comment: I tried to use the app but the result is really strange, for the particular JSON mentioned above in my question I get 3 different files... Is it possible to get it in the swift struct format as mentioned in the previous answer ?

Comment: you can but them in one  file it isn't difficult
, or you can but classes or structs in each other if you want your code to be clean

Comment: yes you can get it in swift struct ,java class ,or objective c ,if you look on the right bottom corner in question image