# Decoding JSON data in swift4 with dates

Tags: json, swift4

Im new at this and having some trouble getting my head around how this all works.

I have this struct:

```
struct EventDetail:Decodable {

    let EventName: String
    let EventInformation: String
    let EventStartDate: Date
    let EventEndDate: Date
}
```

And this func to download the json:

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

    let url = URL(string: "http://someurl.php")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {
            do {


                self.events = try JSONDecoder().decode([EventDetail].self, from: data!)


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

This is the JSON error I get:

> JSON Error
>   typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)), Cosplay_Life.EventDetail.(CodingKeys in _52013DB7ECF3BE1EBFBF83BE6BA8F9E9).EventStartDate], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

This all seems to be working if the `EventStartDate` and `EventEndDate` is a String, but I do wish to have it as a `Date` because I will sort data later using the date field. The value that gets downloaded is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" eks: "2017-02-25" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look for `dateDecodingStrategy` of `JSONDecoder`, and also for `DateFormatter`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting JSON Data with Swift 4 and Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704954/getting-json-data-with-swift-4-and-xcode-9)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A date is a Double in that it is the number of ms since the epoch.

Try this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
// Use format appropriate to your JSON String.  This is for ISO-8601
// You MUST account for the milliseconds even if you don't want them 
// or it won't parse properly
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" 

eventDetail.EventStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: jsonEventStartDateField)!
eventDetail.EventEndDate   = dateFormatter.date(from: jsonEventEndDateField)!
```

Comment: The answer is not related to the question at all. The OP uses `JSONDecoder()` and the date format is clearly **not** ISO8601